# how to find out the number of digits of a number in c++?

Tags: c++

I wanna find out the number of digits of a number in c++ but I don't know what can I do? for example  number of digits 7676575.

Answer (score 12):

Take the ceiling of the base-10 logarithm of the number. (Or more generally "base-*N*" for the number of digits in base *N*.)

In code: `std::ceil(std::log10(n + 1))`, and make sure to `#include <cmath>`.

(You'll get the answer `0` for input `0` as a special case. It's up to you what to do about negative numbers.)

The code in @Knaģis's answer is possibly more efficient, since divisions by the constant 10 can be turned into multiplications by the compiler and are fairly cheap. You have to profile and compare if this is per­formance-critical, and if this applies to integral types only. The logarithm approach also lets you com­pute the number of digits in a hypothetical decimal expansion of very large floating point numbers.

Comment: also needs a check for `n == 0`. plus a call to `abs(n)`

Comment: Still not quite: `std::floor(std::log10(n))+1` (think of n=100).

Comment: sorry,but how can I use it? I wanna save the number of digits

Comment: I need it for multiplication of large numbers in c++

Comment: Hm, what algorithm do you use? Large numbers can be easily multiplied using bit shifts (see wikipedia) and I don't see why you would need number of decimal digits there.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i = 7676575;
int digits = i == 0 ? 1 : 0;
i = abs(i); // handle negative numbers as well
while (i > 0)
{
    digits++;
    i /= 10;
}

// -or- if you prefer do/while then a shorter sample (by Kerrek SB)

int i = 7676575;
int digits = 0;
i = abs(i); // handle negative numbers as well
do { digits++; } while (i /= 10);
```

Comment: +1 This is possibly more efficient than using floating point operations.

Comment: How about `do ++digits while (i /= 10);`?

Comment: And if the input is an integer (which the question didn't state) it may be more accurate than the logarithm based approach, which, for large values of the input, very close to a change in digit count, might occasionally be wrong.  'Cause floating point is very close to right, but not always exact.

Comment: @DRVic: On the other hand, the logarithm can give you the digit count for a number that you could never express as an `int` :-)

Comment: Oddly enough, on some architectures this includes INTEGERS that you could never express as an int (or variant).  Machines exist with 48 bit mantissa on double, but long at 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a string and get its length;

```
int number = getNumberFromSomewhere();

stringstream ss;

ss << number;
size_t numDigits = ss.str().length();
```

Comment: No, putting in a string might be a good idea only for decimal numbers (and only if you can guarantee if `string(1/2)` is not rendered as `0.49999999999999999999`.

Comment: Yep, it works for his examples of an integer though.  Good point about floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
int getdigits(T v)
{
T i = std::abs(v);
if (i < 10) return 1;
else if (i < 100) return 2;
...
else if (i < 100000000) return 8;
else if (i < 1000000000) return 9;
}
```

And so on, you can extend to include long range, not only int. I'm not sure if this is faster than divide, but why not - it's just 10 comparisons.

I suppose templates black magic can be used to generate functions with only needed number of ifs, but who really cares. But you can ensure T is integer using std::enable_if<std::is_integer<T>::value>.

Comment: If this turns out to be faster than the alternatives, and especially if you know something about the distribution of the inputs, re-ordering the tests to be more like binary search could be better.  Are the inputs equally likely to have any number of digits, or are they equally likely to be any value in some range?  If the latter, just working down from the largest to the smallest would be faster, since most of the numbers in the range 0 to 10^n have n digits.

Comment: If you want to optimize you can narrow range like "if (!(i & 0xFFFF0000)) {}" and then perform only 5 ifs. But frankly I do not think that this will be performance-critical code (i.e. avoid premature optimization). I'd just write a range enough to handle ULL numbers and forget it untils profiler tells me something. What's more important is that did topic starter mean floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string and check the length of the string:

```
std::to_string(number).size()
```