# How to cast double FLT_MAX to int?

Tags: c++, windows

I have sometime a return value FLT_MAX or FLT_MAX / 2 from a function.
I must now cast this value to a int or long int for further calculation.

```
#define FLT_MAX          3.402823466e+38F        // max value  

double f =  FLT_MAX;  
long long int n = static_cast<long long int>(f); // result is -9223372036854775808
```

I get this wrong result:  -9223372036854775808 !?
Which data type do I need exactly?

---

Update:
This is the function, which may fall with great great values:

```
int numPlaces(long int n) {
    if (n < 0) return numPlaces((n == INT_MIN) ? INT_MAX : -n);
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    return 1 + numPlaces(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: None? How many bits do you think `long long int` has?

Comment: You need an integer class with about 126 bits to represent flat-max

Comment: `e+38F` when converted to an integer would need about 38 decimal digits. Not even `long long` has that many.

Comment: In C++ do try and use `const` instead of a potentially flaky `#define`.

Comment: If you need to do integer math on something this substantial, find a "bignum" library.

Comment: `long long int` is good for about 20 decimal digits. If you need more than that, chances are pretty good that @tadman is right, and you need a bignum library.

Comment: You need `float`, `double`, or `long double`. An integer type that can hold a value whose magnitude is 10^38 would have to hold well over 100 bits; most implementations don’t have integers that large.

Comment: "Which data type do I need exactly?" only you know. Why do you need a cast? What do you plan to do with the value?

Comment: "I must now cast this value to a int or long int for further calculation." why? I guess the right answer to your problem is to understand that you dont need it

Comment: Check out [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: What I wanted is to optimize a function  `int CountDigits(double float)`  `{ CString str; str.Format(_T("%.0lf"), fabs(fval));  return str.GetLength() - 1 ;} `  with a mathematical expression. It works except for very very great values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find out the number of digits of a number in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348986/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-digits-of-a-number-in-c)

Comment: @RaymondChen if this is faster, then yes. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `#define` like this "`#define FLT_MAX          3.402823466e+38F        // max value`" in C++. Use a `const`ant instead.

Comment: @BoP — `long long` **can have** that many bits. It is not **required** to.

Comment: I was very
 surprised that `double` or even a `float` can hold an bigger value than an `long int`!

Comment: *"I get this wrong result: -9223372036854775808 !?"* -- What would be the correct result? What happens if you try to initialize `n` to the "correct" result using an integer literal (e.g. `long long int n = 34028200000000000000000000000000000000;`)?

Comment: @JaMiT this will give a compiler error: constand too big.

Comment: @TomTom Good. Now consider this: if you had tried this rather straight-forward and easy experiment before posting your question, would you have asked a different question? You could have avoided asking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and instead asked directly about your `numPlaces` function (or maybe you'd want to ask something related to your surprise that `double` can hold a larger value than `long long`). All you need is some practice investigating and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>     // std::string, std::to_string
#define FLT_MAX          3.402823466e+38F        // max value  

int numPlaces(double f) {
    std::string s = std::to_string(f);
    return s.find('.');
}

int main()
{
    double f = FLT_MAX;
    std::cout << numPlaces(f);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the function I want to optimize with an mathematical expression. Format, handling with string is here the bottleneck. @RaymondChan pointed probably to the right direction,  not yet tested.